# Books on Tefillah

Tags: prayer-book, books-generally

Can you tell me of some books/seforim about Jewish prayer (in terms of nusach, development of tefillah, etc.).  A good example would be "[Netiv Binah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34206&pgnum=1)".  They can be either online or in print.

Answer (score 3):

Several I have found helpful:

- [A Guide to Jewish Prayer](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=36100) by Rabbi I. Wohlgemuth.  Might be out of print?
- [To Pray as a Jew](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465086330) by Rabbi Hayim Halevy Donin.
- The [My People's Prayer Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1879045796) series by Rabbi Lawrence A. Hoffman (link is to first book).  There are about ten volumes, one for each part of the weekday/shabbat services, with commentary, historical notes, etc.  A deeper dive than the previous two, but very accessible.
- [Jewish Liturgy: A Comprehensive History](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827604459) by Rabbi Ismar Elbogen, translated by Raymond P. Scheindlin.  Informative but, to me, a more difficult read than the others.

Comment: Neither Rabbi Hoffman nor Rabbi Elbogen are Orthodox. This may affect the content of their books.

Comment: Elbogen is the scholarly classic if you are interested in an historical perspective, although some things have changed due to more recent discoveries (e.g. from genizas), and his discussion of the variations among all of the different nusachot is invaluable

Comment: Re: R. Wohlgemuth, there is now a new edition https://oupress.org/product/beurei-hatefillah/

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of excellent sources.  A recent publication is ["Why We Pray What We Pray" by Rabbi Dr. Barry Freundel.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9655240347)

I also enjoy looking at the [Beurei Hatefila](http://beureihatefila.com/) site developed by Abe Katz, a former student of Rabbi Isaiah Wohlgemuth Z"L who had an excellent mandatory Beurei Hatefila program at my high school.

Answer (score 1):

[My Prayer](http://store.kehotonline.com/index.php?stocknumber=EP-MYPR.S&deptid=3225&parentid=19&page=1&itemsperpage=10) by Nissan Mindel.