# Tefillah Commentaries - Rishonim

Tags: tefilla, product-recommendation, jewish-books, rishonim

Does anyone know of any Rishonim who explain tefillah?

(To clarify: I'm looking for peirushim on the text itself. Mefarshim on the concept of Tefillah in general should be taken [over here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5810/9682).)

Comment: @DoubleAA Still too broad?

Comment: Rambam, Machzor Vitry, Sefer Abudirham... Just the first three that come to mind.

Comment: @ShimonbM Rambam didn't write a commentary to the Siddur. My initial lineup is Mahzor Vitry, Rokeah, Ra'avan (mistakenly attributed to R. Shelomo of Germiza), and Abudirham.

Comment: Don't forget R Yehuda Ben Yakar. @mevaq

Comment: While not an answer to the question, (these Rishonim didn't comment on Tefillah) this may be helpful: There are several siddurim which compile peirushim of the Rishonim (not exclusively though) in other areas which may apply to the Siddur, e.g. siddur shay l'morah and this link: http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Siddur_Ha_Miphorush_Kavanas_Ha_Leiv.pdf

Answer (score 5):

'[Tefilah LeMoshe](https://www.tora-shlema.co.il/?product=%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%91-%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D)' is a collection of commentaries by Rishonim on the siddur's text. Some of the commentaries are:

- [Judah b. Yakar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judah_ben_Yakar)
- [Solomon of Worms](http://hebrewbooks.org/21968)
- [Eliezer b. Nathan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliezer_ben_Nathan)
- School of [Ashkenazi Hasidim](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashkenazi_Hasidim)

Comment: The commentary formerly attributed to R. Shelomo of Worms is actually that of Raavan.

Comment: @mevaqesh Did not know this. Can you kindly provide a source for this? In comparing the siddur of R. Shlomo I linked to and the Raavan quoted throughout the TL which I mention in my answer I two completely different works; both in content and style. It is doubtful that Raavan authored two such works. (Read also the publisher's intro. of the aforementioned siddur.)

Comment: הזכיר הגאון הרב פרופ' חיים הלוי סולוביצ'יק דבאמת נתחבר ע"י הראב"ן, ב-"קולקתד אסייז" ח"א עמ' כא, וכן היה פשוט אצל שלמה טל שספר זו לא יצא מתחת ידו של רבנו שלמה ב-"ברכו אחר קדיש בתרא" הנדפס בסיני (עט) עמ' ק"צ. אלא שכתב שיצא מבית מדרשם של ר"י החסיד והרוקח, (שנולדו כשישים שנה אחרי הראב"ן). וכתב הרב שלמה י' שפיצר ב-"סדר יום הכפורים לראב"ן" הנדפס במוריה (קצט - ר, תשנ"א) עמ' כב, שנתברר ללא כל ספק שהנו זהה לסידורו של הראב"ן. וכן היה פשוט אצל הרב דוד יצחקי ב-"ליקוטי הערות בנוסחאות התפילה" הנדפס בבית אהרן וישראל (מב, תשנ"ב) עמ' ק"ו.

Comment: וכן הביא הרב ישראל מרדכי פלס ב-"סדר מאה ברכות לראב"ן" הנדפס בזכור לאברהם (חולון; תש"ן) עמ' ג', בשם ר' שמואל אליעזר שטרן שליט"א, שבאמת מחברו הראב"ן. וכן ראיתי בשם פרופ' אברהם גרוסמן, בספרו חכמי אשכנז הראשונים, עמ' 346-348.

Comment: @mevaqesh (In my previous comment I think I intended it to read "I *see* two...".) Thanks a lot for the references; particularly curious to see Soloveitchik's arguments. As it stands, I don't see how they'd square off the two uniquely different works I refer to in my earlier comment. As author of the answer, I'm inclined to leave it as is (at least until I can read the sources you cite) since despite their dubious provenance, they're certainly two different commentaries on the siddur.